# What do I need to do to be able to receive my form data in the api?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, next.js, react-forms

Hello I am having a problem saving my purchase order I am not able to receive the form data my code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { parseCookies } from 'nookies';
import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'js-cookie';
import { Segment, Divider, Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import CartItemList from "../components/Cart/CartItemList"
import baseUrl from '../utils/baseUrl';
import catchErrors from '../utils/catchErrors';
import calculateCartTotal from '../utils/calculateCartTotal';

const INITIAL_ORDER = {
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    address: ""
};


const Cart = ({ products, user }) => {
    // console.log(products)
    const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = React.useState(products);
    const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const [cartAmout, setCartAmaount] = React.useState(0);
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState(INITIAL_ORDER);
    const [isCartEmpty, setCartEmpty] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const { cartTotal } = calculateCartTotal(products);
        setCartAmaount(cartTotal);
        setCartEmpty(products.length === 0)
    }, [products]);

    const handleChanhe = e => {
        // console.log(d.value)
        const { name, value} = e.target;
        if(name === 'media'){
            setOrder(prevState => ({ ...prevState, media: files[0]}))
            setMediaPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
        } else {
            setOrder(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
        }
         console.log(order);
    }

    const handleRemoveFromCart = async (productId) => {
        const url = `${baseUrl}/api/cart`;
        const token = cookie.get("token");
        const payload = {
            params: {productId},
            headers: {Authorization: token}
        };
        const response = await axios.delete(url, payload);
        setCartProducts(response.data);
    }

    const handleCheckout = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/checkout2`;
            const token = cookie.get("token");
            const {phone, email, address} = order;
            const payload = {phone, email, address};
            const headers = {headers: {Authorization: token}};
            await axios.post(url, payload, headers);
            setOrder(INITIAL_ORDER);
            setSuccess(true);
        } catch (error) {
            catchErrors(error, window.alert);
            console.log(order)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="cart-area">
            <Segment loading={loading}>
                <CartItemList 
                    handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
                    user={user} 
                    products={cartProducts} 
                    success={success}
                />
                <React.Fragment>
            <Divider />
            <Segment clearing size="large" >
            <strong>Sub total:</strong> ${cartAmout}
                <Form success={success} onSubmit={handleCheckout}>
                    <Form.Input
                        fluid
                        icon="phone"
                        iconPosition="left"
                        label="Telefone"
                        placeholder="Tel"
                        name="phone"
                        type="text"
                        value={order.phone}
                        onChange={handleChanhe}
                    />
                    <Form.Input
                        fluid
                        icon="envelope"
                        iconPosition="left"
                        label="Email"
                        placeholder="e-mail"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        value={order.email}
                        onChange={handleChanhe}
                    />
                    <Form.Input
                        fluid
                        icon="shipping"
                        iconPosition="left"
                        label="Rua e Numero"
                        placeholder="Rua e Nº"
                        name="address"
                        type="text"
                        value={order.address}
                        onChange={handleChanhe}
                    />
                    <Form.Button
                        control={Button}
                        type="submit"
                        icon="cart"
                        color="green"
                        floated="right"
                        content="Checkout"
                        disabled={isCartEmpty || success}
                    />
                </Form>
            </Segment>

        </React.Fragment>
            </Segment>
        </div>
    );
}

Cart.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);
    if (!token){
        return { products: [] };
    }
    const url = `${baseUrl}/api/cart`;
    const payload = { headers: {Authorization: token} };
    const response = await axios.get(url, payload);
    return { products: response.data };
}

export default Cart;
```

Now here's my checkout api:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import Cart from '../../models/Cart';
import Order from '../../models/Order';
import calculateCartTotal from '../../utils/calculateCartTotal';


export default async (req, res) => {
    const { paymentData } = req.body;
     console.log(paymentData) 
    try {
        const {userId} = jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const cart = await Cart.findOne({ user: userId }).populate({
            path: "products.product",
            model: "Product"
        });
        const {cartTotal} = calculateCartTotal(cart.products);
        
        await new Order({
            user: userId,
            email: paymentData.email,
            address: paymentData.address,
            phone: paymentData.phone,
            total: cartTotal,
            products: cart.products
        }).save();

        await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: cart._id},
            {$set: {products: []}}
        )

        res.status(200).send("Checkout successful!");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Error proccessing charge");
    }
}
```

My constant is not receiving form data, just to make clear the user and product data I am receiving correctly.The big problem is that the paymentData constant does not receive what is coming from the form in the handleCheckout function

And finally my order model,

```
// Order Model
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Product from './Product';

const { ObjectId, String, Number } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    products: [
        {
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            },
            product: {
                type: ObjectId,
                ref: Product
            }
        }
    ],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'pending',
        enum: ["pending", "delivered"]
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

export default mongoose.models.Order || mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

Comment: Did you add body-parser library npm in express project?

Comment: No, it really can be that, I'll try, But I need help with that, should I install npm install body-parser and import it at checkout?

Comment: I'm not using express, I'm working with next.js

Comment: Please, could you give code sandbox to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your CodeSandbox and its fails because you are trying to get property of undefined in `api/checkout2` when you do this:

```js
const {paymentData} = req.body;
```

And you have this in `Cart.js`

```js
 const handleCheckout = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/checkout2`;
            const token = cookie.get("token");
            const {phone, email, address} = order;
            const payload = {phone, email, address};
            const headers = {headers: {Authorization: token}};
            await axios.post(url, payload, headers); //Not exists paymentData in body object
            setOrder(INITIAL_ORDER);
            setSuccess(true);
        } catch (error) {
            catchErrors(error, window.alert);
            console.log(order)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
```

You are waiting in `api/Checkout2`object `paymentData`

## There are 2 Solutions:

### 1

you need to create a new object with key `paymentData` and value `payload`

`Cart.js`

```js
const handleCheckout = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/checkout2`;
            const token = cookie.get("token");
            const {phone, email, address} = order;
            const payload = {phone, email, address};
            const headers = {headers: {Authorization: token}};
            await axios.post(url, {paymentData: payload}, headers);
            setOrder(INITIAL_ORDER);
            setSuccess(true);
        } catch (error) {
            catchErrors(error, window.alert);
            console.log(order)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
```

And nothing to change in `api/checkout2`

### 2

Nothing to change in `Cart.js`

In `api/checkout2`:

Change this

```
const { paymentData } = req.body;
```

by

```
const {phone, email, address} = req.body;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Thanks to your help I will be able to complete my project